# Develop Android app without using Estimote location sdk

Tags: android, ios, location, estimote

I'm currently working with Estimote locations beacons. I want to develop an Android application without using Estimote locations SDK. I don't have a clear idea about how to develop and as I read Estimote documentation they are supporting core locations only with the IOS.

Is there are any way to develop the Android app without using location SDK or without using their cloud services?

Comment: As a quick comment: Yes. It's of course possible to scan for the beacons either directly with [Android's Bluetooth LE API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) or some other library, like e.g. the free [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/).

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Estimote sdk? 
You don't need to use the Estimote sdk, you can use every sdk that follows the eddystone (Google) protocol. source: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/204100866-Do-I-have-to-use-Estimote-SDK-What-are-the-benefits-

Comment: @washichi as I read if we use estimote location sdk, we have to pay for their cloud services. that's why I have planed to develop application without using location sdk

Comment: Which kind of format are your Estimote using for advertising? iBeacon? Eddystone?

Comment: @AndreaGorrieri  I'm going to use Estimote location beacons for indoor mapping kind of application